# error:""_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:" in Xcode4.3

Tags: ios5, cordova, xcode4.3, cordova-2.0.0

I am new to iphone develop and phonegap also. Now i want to create simple iphone app using phonegap. Now i am using phonegap2.0 in lion mac. MY Xcode version is 4.3. Now my issue is after install the phonegap2.0 in xcode when i run the Xcode in my Simulator 5.0. I got this below error.

```
"Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance. 
And i have attach the Screen Shot of error page for your reference. 
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check if your project links `libCordova.a` (in my case Xcode forgot about the reference, when moving CordovaLib.xcodeproj to another location).

- select your project in the **Project Navigator**
- go to the **Summary** tab
- drag `CordovaLib.xcodeproj > Products > libCordova.a` to **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**

[image]

Clean & build.

Answer (score 3):

Please check your ViewController.m file and goto to 
1. Build phase in xcode 
2. Select Compile Sources
3. Press + button to add .m/.mm file

I think it will run successfully now

Comment: "Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Soory. Now i got the Above same error. Then what is that .m/.mm file. Sorry. I can't get that message. Sorry.

Comment: .m/.mm file means ViewController.m /ViewController.mm file or any other viewController .m or .mm file(Source code).Please add all .m or .mm file to Build Phase->Compile Sources.Then clean your project and build again.

Answer (score 2):

Remove armv7s from your build settings, for both your project and the referenced subproject Cordova.  Set your target to 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Somehow my the NSManagedObject Sub-classes of my Core Data entities were in the Compile Sources table twice. The compiler would choke when it hit the first of these duplicates.

I just went into the Compile Sources table and deleted the second occurrence of each .m listing.